# 'Web3' object has no attribute 'isConnected'

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ethereum, web3py

I am trying to connect to the Ethereum blockchain with Web3. When I install web3 using jupyter notebook I keep receiving the error that Web3 has no attribute. Can someone please advise on how to get connected to the Ethereum network?

**MY CODE**:

```
pip install web3

from web3 import Web3, EthereumTesterProvider
w3 = Web3(EthereumTesterProvider())
w3.isConnected()
```

**ERROR**:

```
AttributeError Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [29], in <cell line: 3>()
  1 from web3 import EthereumTesterProvider
  2 w3 = Web3(EthereumTesterProvider())
----> 3 w3.isConnected()

AttributeError: 'Web3' object has no attribute 'isConnected'
```

I have tried both web3 and capital Web3 and still receive the same error. I have also tried

```
w3 = Web3(Web3.EthereumTesterProvider())
```

but same issues.

Answer (score 11):

Please try `is_connected()` instead of `isConnected()`.

Comment: This was changed in Web3 6.0 release to conform with Python coding conventions. The release was made last week.

Comment: For Python version 3.10 works!

Answer (score 0):

Web3py has started using snakecase instead of CamelCase, So try is_connected()